# Change colors from default to custom in Flutter for dark mode?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to change the theme of my app, but the primary color of my app is green. I've seen so much resolutions but I am got confused how to set a light theme not blue, but green. Should I put inside this line of code the custom primary color or I should put it in the root if my app?

The code:

```
class ThemeProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  ThemeData _selectedTheme;
  Typography defaultTypography;
  SharedPreferences prefs;

  ThemeData dark = ThemeData.dark().copyWith();

  ThemeData light = ThemeData.light().copyWith();

  ThemeProvider(bool darkThemeOn) {
    _selectedTheme = darkThemeOn ? dark : light;
  }
```

the main:

```
 return MaterialApp(
        theme: value.getTheme(),
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: MapPage(),
        routes: {'favorite': (_) => Homescreen()},
      );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already have your dark and light ThemeData, you can adjust the primary color there:

```
final ThemeData darkTheme = new ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
   primaryColor: Colors.green
);
```

With this you can adjust the two themes as you wish.